# Subset columns of one data frame (by name) by information from second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would appreciate a solution for the following problem: I have the following example data frame:

```
df1 = data_frame(Tom = c(1,2,3,4), Tina = c(5,6,7,8), Todd = c(9,10,11,12), Brit = c(1,2,3,4))
```

I have a second data frame with information about Tom, Tina etc.

```
 df2 = data_frame(ID = c("Tom","Todd","Tina","Brit"), value = c(1,3,2,1))
```

Now I would like to subset colums from data frame df1 if the "value" in df2 fulfils a particular condition, e.g. df2$value = 1 | df2$value = 2 
The resulting table should look like:

```
desired_result_look_like = data_frame(Tom = c(1,2,3,4), Tina = c(5,6,7,8), Brit = c(1,2,3,4))
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I didn't get your condition logic. If your `df2` contains value `1 or 2`, you remove `Tina` column from `df1`?

Comment: @TheBiro. Sorry, yes, my fault. Todd should be removed and Tina should be "in"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using row values in one data frame to select the columns in another data frame, the solution isn't particularly clean, but if you wanted to stick with this approach, you could create a third data frame that filters the second data frame based on your conditions, then select the column names in the first data frame that correspond with values in the  filtered data frame. The code would look something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df2_filtered <- df2 %>% filter(value == 1 | value == 2)
desired_result <- df1[ , colnames(df1) %in% df2_filtered$ID]
```

(This is operating under the assumption that in your posted "desired result", you meant to include Tina instead of Todd)

Comment: Yes, Todd should be removed and Tina should be "in". I edited the original post.